# Jquery val() doesn't return the correct value , it returns a truncated value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code (it's for a slider):

```
<form name="volume">
  Volume(investor transactions)
 <output name="volumeOutputName" id="volumeOutputId" style="float:right;" >306789</output> <input type="range" name="volumeInputName" id="volumeInputId" value="306789" min="250000" max="1000000" oninput="volumeOutputId.value = volumeInputId.value" class="slider" step="50000">  
&nbsp;
</form>
```

In the js file I do this :

```
var Ke=$("#volumeInputId").val();
console.log(Ke);
```

And the output is 300000, not 306789 as it should be . Why?

Comment: Why is `306789` correct when the `step` value is `50000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `step=50000` to `step=1` in your `input` parameters, otherwise you are limiting the accuracy of your slider to steps of 50,000.

The example below gives the answer you are looking for, I've also added a little bit of jquery that prints to the console each time the value is changed so you can test it.

```js
var Ke=$("#volumeInputId").val();
console.log(Ke);

$("#volumeInputId").change( function() {
      console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="volume">

Volume(investor transactions) <output name="volumeOutputName" id="volumeOutputId" style="float:right;" >306789</output> <input type="range" name="volumeInputName" id="volumeInputId" value="306789" min="250000" max="1000000" oninput="volumeOutputId.value = volumeInputId.value" class="slider" step="1">                   &nbsp;
</form>
```